# SignalR - Preserve Same Connection Across Multiple Pages of Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'd like to provide a user experience where a SignalR connection is available across multiple pages in my ASP.NET MVC application.

If I include SignalR startup code (JS) in my _Layout.cshtml, will that be perceived by the server as a "fresh" client connection every time the user navigates to a different page?  Or will SignalR support this kind of behavior out of the box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each page is represented as a "Client" so therefore you will have a unique connection per page (no way around that).  Alternatives to this issue are:

1. Dynamically load pages and display them on current page.  Essentially only having one physical page.
2. Save user state in a cookie or session and when you start a new connection fill it with your saved state.  Be wary of security issues with this approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Regarding your option #1 - sounds like a Single-Page Application would handle this very nicely!